# How can I sort and use my SQL data once its in python?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sorting, iterator

I am importing a large amount of data from SQL server to python for some mathematical analysis. I have successfully imported it using pandas but I can't figure out a way in python to sort it in the way I want.
The data I'm importing has the following format.

```
        pick            #         X              Y
00006630519697559571    1   1572.0000000    255.0000000
00006630519697559571    2   1642.0000000    189.0000000
00006630519697559571    3   1717.0000000    279.0000000
00006630519697559571    4   1326.0000000    337.0000000
00006630519697571696    1   1290.0000000    87.0000000
00006630519697571696    2   1806.0000000    133.0000000
00006630519697571696    3   1431.0000000    214.0000000
00006630519697571696    4   1431.0000000    226.0000000
```

And what I'm doing is summing the distance driven between all items in each pick using python which I have been able to do for individual picks. The issue I'm having though is that I need to do the same thing for all the picks individually (there are around 12,700 of them) but I can't figure out how to separate the data by pick and then perform the necessary calculations on each set. Any help on this issue would be much appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the sql-server before you are importing the data which should be much faster than doing it using pandas.
Just execute the following SQL statement against your server after you replaced "TABLENAME" with the name of the table you are querying.

```
SELECT pick, SUM(X), SUM(Y)
FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY pick;
```

If you do not want to do this you can also do a group-by using pandas.

`df.groupby(['pick']).sum()`

Comment: This would work if I were just adding up the x and y values but in reality I have a full python code that is meant to sum the driving distance from one point to another through a defined grid system.

Comment: In that case, since you said you already have a function to do that for a single `pick` you should be able to use `df.groupby(['pick']).apply()` to perform your function for every grouping.  You can read more on that here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#flexible-apply